# Python with Netbeans 6.5

Tags: python, netbeans, project

Can you give me some links or explain how to configure an existing python project onto Netbeans? 
I'm trying it these days and it continues to crash also code navigation doesn't work well and I've problems with debugging. Surely these problems are related to my low eperience about python and I need support also in trivial things as organizing source folders, imports ecc,, thank you very much. 
Valerio

Answer (score 1):

Python support is in beta, and as someone who works with NB for a past 2 years, I can say that even a release versions are buggy and sometimes crashes. Early Ruby support was also very shaky.